# AppleTV app on Mac - have episode play on separate monitor (not macbook)

Tags: appletv

Is it possible to specify which external full screen monitor to use for the AppleTV app on a Macbook? It seems to always default to the Macbook screen even when the app is maximized in an external monitor.